# jquery how to get Text from dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I got 2 pages.. but I am having difficulty getting the Text value from a dropdownlist and inserting it into a textbox for instance this is Page 1

- A user has 1 options to select on Page 1, the jquery code below is activated with the change function .
- This will Load a new dropdownlist depending on which field they picked.
- This all works Fine but my problem is getting the new value from the newlist into the keyword textbox how can i do that ?

  ```
  <select id="pick">
  <option></option>
   <option>Financial</option>
  </select>

  <div id="newlist" style="margin-left:180px;">      
  </div>

     <input type="text" id="keyword" />
  <script>
      $("#pick").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Financial")
  {
           $("#newlist").load('/Listings/service #service');
            $("#keyword").text() = $("#service").text();
        }

    });
  </script>
  ```

page2 is where the newlist is

```
<select name="service" id="service" style="background-color:red;">
<option>automotive</option>
<option>mechanic</option>
</select>
```

So again the   gets the dropdownlist from Page2 but for some reason I can't transfer that value into the  textbox any help would be great..

Comment: try using `$("#keyword").val() = $("#service").val();` instead

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the last part of code should be executed in the complete event.

```
  $("#newlist").load('/Listings/service #service',function(){
          $("#keyword").val($("#service").text());
});
```

Cause `#service` is not gonna be available until your ajax request has completed.

**EDIT:** and as @tymeJV correctly said, it should be `.val()` on the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `val` instead of `text`.

### val

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.

### text

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

Code:

```
 $("#pick").change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == "Financial") {
        $("#keyword").val($("#service").val());
     }
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/TKeE6/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#keyword").val($("#service").val());
```